# xsd validation- child selection depending on parent

Tags: xml, xsd

A parent tag named as 'Refuse' is an optional tag. Further, there are 2 child tags named as 'option1' and 'option2'. If the parent tag value appears in the request, then at least one child must be given and at most 2 children . But, if parent doesn't appear then none of the children should appear.

How can this choice be done among 2 child tags?

Code:

```
<xs:element name="Refuse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">                  
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>                           
        <xs:element name="option1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="5" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="option2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using choice, for example:

```
 <xs:element name="Refuse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">                  
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>                           
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="option1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="option1"/>
            <xs:element ref="option2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="option2"
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xselement>

<xs:element name="option1" >
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="option2">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

The Choice element in the schema allows one and only one of the defined sequences to occur. For more info on choice check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_choice.asp)

For ease of use and to avoid duplicate code I have seperated the definition of the option1 and option2 elements.

Comment: I tried this code, but unfortunately, I was getting an error as : local complex type: The content model is not determinist. [Line : <xs:complexType>]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using choice

```
<xs:element name="Refuse" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">                  
<xs:complexType>
    **<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">**
        **<xs:element name="option1">**
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="5" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        **<xs:element name="option2">**
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: You are aware that this allows for the occurrence of one of the option twice? So for example   <Refuse><option1/><option1/></Refuse>  Is that according to the spec or not? I went on the assumption that you stil only wanted each option at most once.  As suggested by the maxOccurs="1" in the original question.

Comment: @ophychius I wasn't aware that option1 can occur twice. Your assumption is correct, that there is need of each option at the most once.